# A Comprehensive Regular Expression to find URL, links,page links, website links from HTML Page or String

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have searched alot about regular exprasions but i have not found any Comprehensive  Expression. some of them which i have found in internet are dtecting only https or http lniks not other and wise virsa
is there any Comprehensive expression for all of these ???

like:

```
    www.google.com
https://www.fb.com
http://ww.google.com
google.com
info/contact.php
www.google.com.uk
```

and much more

is there any

Comment: I imagine there is, but it might be a very ugly expression unless you're an expert in RegEx.  I'd strongly suggest looking at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing, rather than building your own RegEx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/161738

Comment: Html is not a regular language. Use the right tool for the job, an html parser.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

You can find a lot of examples and patterns there and there are a lot of general Regex tutorials and articles.

After a quick browse I found this :

```
([\d\w-.]+?\.(a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwz]|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|c[acdfghiklmnoruvxyz]|d[ejkmnoz]|e[ceghrst]|f[ijkmnor]|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|h[kmnrtu]|i[delmnoqrst]|j[emop]|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|n[acefgilopruz]|om|p[aefghklmnrstwy]|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvyz]|t[cdfghjkmnoprtvwz]|u[augkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw]|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|info|int|gov|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro)(\b|\W(?<!&|=)(?!\.\s|\.{3}).*?))(\s|$)
```

Should do the trick, but I'm sure there are more elegant examples on that list.